# Azure stream anaytics with PowerBi Fails

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream anaytics job which gets data from IoT hub and sends it to PowerBi and azure data lake. Writing data azure data lake works alone perfectly but when I try to stream data to powerbi my steam analytics job fails after writing first out put and I am getting following error log.

```
{
    "channels": "Operation",
    "correlationId": "ff2593c9-cda2-498c-8e1f-6f13260ae32f",
    "description": "Stream Analytics job status changed for last user action [Start job 'AVLStreamAnalytics'].",
    "eventDataId": "953665c1-aec0-482d-852c-fdf3160cd6fb",
    "eventName": {
        "value": "Start job 'AVLStreamAnalytics'",
        "localizedValue": "Start job 'AVLStreamAnalytics'"
    },
    "category": {
        "value": "Administrative",
        "localizedValue": "Administrative"
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2017-07-13T16:35:46.2226177Z",
    "id": "/subscriptions/161fc731-59a3-4173-9cf5-866b3188abf3/resourceGroups/AVLPOC/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/AVLStreamAnalytics/events/953665c1-aec0-482d-852c-fdf3160cd6fb/ticks/636355605462226177",
    "level": "Error",
    "operationId": "2e5ed092-bb88-4dde-8e9f-2a9c0adc1f78",
    "operationName": {
        "value": "Start job 'AVLStreamAnalytics'",
        "localizedValue": "Start job 'AVLStreamAnalytics'"
    },
    "resourceGroupName": "AVLPOC",
    "resourceProviderName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics"
    },
    "resourceType": {
        "value": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs"
    },
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/161fc731-59a3-4173-9cf5-866b3188abf3/resourceGroups/AVLPOC/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/AVLStreamAnalytics",
    "status": {
        "value": "Failed",
        "localizedValue": "Failed"
    },
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "",
        "localizedValue": ""
    },
    "submissionTimestamp": "2017-07-13T16:35:59.7904001Z",
    "subscriptionId": "161fc731-59a3-4173-9cf5-866b3188abf3",
    "properties": {
        "JobFailedMessage": "The streaming job failed.",
        "JobId": "ff2593c9-cda2-498c-8e1f-6f13260ae32f",
        "JobRunId": "d43b6623-3f9a-4e88-8c7d-21f8788e5cdd",
        "JobRunCreatedDateTime": "2017-07-13 16:31:17Z",
        "JobRunLastUpdateDateTime": "2017-07-13 16:35:46Z",
        "JobRunStatus": "Failed",
        "JobContentVersion": "1.10",
        "JobFrameworkVersion": "1.2.61907.22"
    },
    "relatedEvents": []
}
```

Any ideas why job fails would be perfect. I am quite sure that I ma within limits of power bi app.

Comment: Normally, we can find useful information from activity log, but the error message ``"JobFailedMessage": "The streaming job failed."`` that you get is very generic, it is difficult to figure out the problem. I'd like to know if you test your queries with sample data files before start the Job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authorize the Power BI subscription from within Stream Analytics.